# Jenkins Trigger Kind details in build logs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, gitops, fluxcd

I am using the flux notification controller to trigger my Jenkins Job whenever there is a change in **event source** `"HelmRelease", "kustomization" and "Git Repository"`
Can I track it in Jenkins build logs and check which **event source** causes triggers in the Jenkins pipeline?
Example any stage which I can add:

```
  stages {
    stage('Always') {
      steps {
        echo "I am always executed"
      }
    }
```

Like above if I can check and stage for event sources.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks